# Can permissioned blockchain nodes be changed frequently being selected from a white list?

Tags: networking, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, bitcoin, consensus

I need to implement a permissioned blockchain where nodes can be changed, based on a selection in a white list. Is there a way to implement this? I am reviewing hyperledger fabric, but I can't understand if I can change nodes after deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric allows for the use of a certificate authority which can provide x.509 certificates to new nodes joining the network. This allows for nodes to be added after deployment. See [this part of the docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/identity/identity.html)
Nodes on your whitelist can be authorised/de-authorised by the Membership Service Provider(MSP)

Comment: ok, but is there a way to dinamically change nodes? I mean, with a high frequency, like changing all of them in one hour

Comment: Yeah, sure, the nodes are authorised by the Certificate Authority so as long as new nodes are verified they can be hot-swapped at will. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/identity/identity.html#certificate-authorities